# How to ensure didSelectRowAtIndexPath opens correct View

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, didselectrowatindexpath

I know how to send the user to a new cell after they select a cell but what if the order of my cells change because I am retrieving data from Parse so for each new cell, the row number changes.

How do I ensure the user is sent to the correct page when they select a certain cell? This is what I'm currently using but I know there's got to be a better solution than hardcoding every possible option..

Any advice?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toSettingsPage", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For my understanding of your questions, I suggest you use a `NSMutableDictionary` to store all the user info data, and on the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function, you will use the `indexPath` to find the correct user info.

Answer (score 0):

Your input:

- A table view
- An index path (section, row) ordered pair

Your output:

- A string that identifies a segue

An ideal data structure for this is a dictionary.

First, notice that the table view input is always the same (you only seem to care about one table view - the protocol for data source is written to handle as many table views as you like, but most people use one for one).

Second, think about your keys and values: your key is the index path. And in fact, the index path breaks down into just an `Integer` because it is always the same section, which is analogous to the situation with table view described above.

So your dictionary is going to be of type: `Dictionary<Integer, String>`.

Now, instead of using the dictionary directly, let's make a function to wrap it and call the function `segueForIndexPathInDefaultTableView`:

```
private let seguesForIndexPaths:[Integer:String] = [0:"segue0",1:"segue1",2:"segue2"]

private func segueForIndexPathInDefaultTableView(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    return self.seguesForIndexPaths[indexPath.row]
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {      
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.segueForIndexPathInDefaultTableView(indexPath: indexPath), sender:self)
}
```

Comment: How do I create the segue since the user is the one creating the post? User creates post-> when another user taps on it, the next view needs to display with the correct info from the original post. Does that make sense?